# Getting error in Codeigniter Database for deleting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to delete the question based on id_comprhensive which is on the other table.

Here is my controller

```
public function delete_question($c){
    $this->load->model("admindata");
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->admindata->deletequestion($c);
}
```

Here is my model.

```
function deletequestion($k){
        $hasil = $this->db->query("DELETE question FROM question JOIN main ON main.id_question = question.id_question WHERE main.id_comp = $k");
        $query = $hasil->result();

        return $query;
    }
```

Whenever I tried to run it, it was always error. The error is this :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\2016\2016_02_15_Quiz\application\models\admindata.php on line 576**

What's wrong with my code ? I have plenty of query in admindata.php, but I just got error on this function.

Comment: do you try without result() ..... like $hasil = $this->db->query("DELETE question FROM question JOIN main ON main.id_question = question.id_question WHERE main.id_comp = $k"); return $hasil;

Comment: The error has gone. But I still can't delete the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this below code:

```
function deletequestion($k){
   $this->db->from("question");
   $this->db->join("main", "main.id_question = question.id_question");
   $this->db->where("main.id_comp", $k);
   $query = $this->db->delete("question");
   return $query;
}
```

You can also try to remove foreign key check:

```
function deletequestion($k){
    $hasil = $this->db->query("
                         SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
                         DELETE question FROM question JOIN main ON main.id_question = question.id_question
                         WHERE main.id_comp = $k
                         SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
                      ");
    $query = $hasil->result();

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nadimul De CJ.. The problem is in foreign_key.. The foreign_key doesn't exist because I erase it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

*Your query returns true or false, not an array so just try this*

```
function deletequestion($k){
        $hasil = $this->db->query("DELETE question FROM question JOIN main ON main.id_question = question.id_question WHERE main.id_comp = $k");
        print_r($hasil);


    }
```

*And if it displays 1 your query is fine ,if it displays 0 your query is not deleted*